# How to rename many variables in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

How to rename many variables in ggplotly?

When I scroll over the interactive graphs, the names are not pleasant to look at. I want to format them to include spacing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `tibble`, the `tidyverse`'s take on the `data.frame`.

```
library(tibble)
my_tbl <- tibble(`Nice variable 1` = runif(10),
                 `Special?Characters?` = runif(10),
                 `:)` = runif(10))
my_tbl
```

Use `my_tbl` as input to your `ggplot` object e.g. `ggplot(data = my_tbl)` then wrap that `ggplot` object with `ggplotly`.